# How to know the last element of a byte pointer?

Tags: c++

I need to know what the last byte of this pointer is.

NULL, 0, nullptr, '\0'...  does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
//------------------------------------------------------------------
struct MyStruct
{
    int myNumber;
    char c[10];
    std::string s;
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------
int GetSize(char *data)
{
    char* ptr = data;
    int size = 0;

    for (char* it = ptr; it!= nullptr; it++, size++)//<-- it does not work
    {
        std::cout << "size-->" << size << std::endl;
    }

    return size;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    MyStruct data;

    std::cout << "size-->" << sizeof(MyStruct) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size-->" << sizeof(data) << std::endl;
    system("pause");    
    

    GetSize((char*)&data);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way to do it?

The code has been extended by community request.

Comment: You need to check `*it`, not `it`.

Comment: Not possible in C/++, which is why you'll typically see functions with the following heads: `void foo(const char* fooArray, const size_t fooArraySize)`

Comment: If you want to have a finite array of bytes, you need to use an `std::array`, or an `std::vector` (or come up with your own type, but I wouldn't recommend it).
The reason is that C/++ allow you to work on the lowest level, meaning you can directly manipulate areas of memory, which other languages like Java and C# (to an extent!) don't.

Comment: Ok, The code has been extended

Comment: You cannot determine the size of arrays in a called function in C++. You need to know the size before calling the function.

Comment: wow, why are you doing this? You cannot determine the size of an object like that

Comment: It is possible to determine the length of a null-terminated string by iterating through every character of the string until you find the null terminator. However, this does not determine the actual size of the array, only the length of the string it contains. And it only works with null-terminated strings. It does not work with other types of objects.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel there is no null-terminates string, `data` is a `MyStruct*` reinterpreted as `char*`

Comment: `MyStruct` is not a POD. This will not end the way you think it will. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I need to convert any data structure to an array<uint8>  and vice versa... so i need to know the size in bytes

Comment: "I need to convert any data structure to an array<uint8> and vice versa.: This is generally not possible and I would not recommend trying it.

Comment: you already know the size, it is `sizeof(MyStruct)`. Though, this sounds like you aim for some sort of serialization, and `std::string` cannot be serialized like that. I mean you can easily get the `array<uint8>` from the `std::string` but it will be rather useless

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Your question here (the X) has been answered, but all mentioned here will not help you for your Y: How to convert to byte array and back. If you need help with that you can open a new question

Comment: It is the only format that supports writing files in the cloud (EOS), there is no other way to do it....  https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Plugins/OnlineSubsystem/Interfaces/IOnlineUserCloud/WriteUserFile/

Comment: read about serialization. Its a very typical C++ thingy, it looks straight forward when approached naively, but it is actually rather involved and not trival

Comment: @IvánRodríguez "*I need to convert any data structure to an array<uint8> and vice versa...*" - that is called **serialization**. You can't copy the raw bytes of your `MyStruct` as-is to a byte array and back, because `MyStruct` is not a [POD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType) ("plain old data") type, as it contains a `std::string`, which is also not a POD. There are *numerous* posts on StackOverflow that demonstrate how to serialize non-POD types correctly.

Comment: It was just a test structure. I'll probably just use it to store integers. Thank you very much for telling me about serialization. I will look for information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you wish to serialize it to binary.

*How* that works is up to you. I tend to prefer length-prefixed strings.

```
[ 4 BYTES] myNumber
[10 BYTES] c
[ 4 BYTES] s.size()
[ N BYTES] s.data()
```

Some people prefer nul-terminated strings.

```
[ 4 BYTES] myNumber
[10 BYTES] c
[ N BYTES] s.c_str() // includes the terminating nul
```

You can compute the size requirements to *store* the data easily enough:

```
size_t byte_size_for( const MyStruct & S )
{
  return 4 + 10 + 4 + s.size();
}
```

Or for the nul-terminated version:

```
size_t byte_size_for( const MyStruct & S )
{
  return 4 + 10 + s.size() + 1;
}
```

Serializing an integer is a bit trickier than you’d think. Converting TO little-endian bytes is actually the easiest one to do.

```
namespace little_endian
{
  void to_bytes( signed long long value, unsigned char * buffer, unsigned size )
  {
    while (size--)
    {
      *buffer++ = (unsigned char)(value & 0xFF);
      value >>= 8;
    }
  }
} // namespace little_endian
```

Going the other way is a bit tricky just for deserialization of the signed, little-endian integer value.

```
namespace big_endian
{
  void from_bytes( unsigned long long & value, unsigned char * buffer, unsigned size )
  {
    while (size--)
    {
      value <<= 8;
      value |= *buffer++;
    }
  }
} // namespace big_endian

namespace little_endian
{
  template <typename Integer>
  void from_bytes( Integer & value, unsigned char * buffer, unsigned size )
  {
    std::reverse( buffer, buffer+size );
    unsigned long long n = std::is_signed<Integer>::value ? ~0ULL : 0;
    big_endian::to_bytes( n, buffer, size );
    value = (Integer) n;
  }
} // namespace little_endian
```

At least now we can serialize our structure to and from bytes:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> to_bytes( const MyStruct & S )
{
  std::vector<unsigned char> bytes( byte_size_for( S ) );
  little_endian::to_bytes( (signed long long)S.myNumber, (unsigned char *)bytes.data(), 4 );
  std::copy( S.c, S.c+10, (unsigned char *)bytes.data()+4 );
  little_endian::to_bytes( (signed long long)S.s.size(), (unsigned char *)bytes.data()+4+10, 4 );
  std::copy( S.s.begin(), S.s.end(), (unsigned char *)bytes.data()+4+10+4 );
  return bytes;
}

bool from_bytes( MyStruct & S, std::vector<unsigned char> bytes )
{
  if (bytes.size() < 4+10+4) return false;
  little_endian::from_bytes( S.myNumber, (unsigned char *)bytes.data(), 4 );
  std::copy( bytes.data()+4, bytes.data()+4+10, S.c );
  size_t n;
  little_endian::from_bytes( n, (unsigned char *)bytes.data()+4+10, 4 );
  std::copy( bytes.data()+4+10+4, bytes.data()+4+10+4+n, std::back_inserter( S.s ) );
  return true;
}
```

Using it is easy:

```
MyStruct my_struct;

auto bytes = to_bytes( my_struct );

from_bytes( my_struct, bytes );
```

If you are writing the data to and reading from some binary file, you still need to know how to read the correct number of bytes from file. But that is the point of having a strict binary definition, like I started first thing with at the very top.

Anyway...

Comment: I’m glad you’ve made sense of it. Dealing with non-textual data is where things get rough and ugly.

Answer (score 2):

If this was just to exercise then the lesson to learn is: No. It does not work like that.

You can cast the pointer to `MyStruct` to a pointer to `char` and you can inspect the bytes via that pointer. So far so good. However, there is no way to know the size of `MyStruct` given only that `char*`.

You already know the size of `MyStruct` it is `sizeof(MyStruct)`. You could write the loop like this:

```
for (int i=0; i< sizeof(MyStruct); ++i,++data)
{
    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(*data) << std::endl;
}
```

This way you can read the data as if it was a stream of bytes.

The pointer `data` will never equal `nullptr` or `0` or `\0` by incrementing it. With some luck the byte it points to, `*data`, might equal `0`, but it will not be at the end of the object.

You cannot determine the size of `MyStruct` given only a `char*` pointing to an instance.

---

For your question literally:

> How to know the last element of a byte pointer?

You can see what the last byte is via `data[ sizeof(MyStruct) -1]` (when printing you might want to cast to `unsigned` as above, because otherwise it will be printed as character, possibly non-printable).