# C not calculating bitwise operations properly

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a list of 16-bit (unsigned shorts) blocks which I receive from another part of program which I want to write to a binary file. I am trying to split these into 8-bit characters so I devised this method:

```c
int blocks = 1;
unsigned short stuffToWrite[blocks];
stuffToWrite[0] = 0b0100101011110111;

int charsPerBlock = sizeof(unsigned short) / sizeof(char);

char charsToWrite[blocks * charsPerBlock];

for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < charsPerBlock; j++) {
        charsToWrite[i*charsPerBlock+j] = (stuffToWrite[i] & ((((int) pow(2, sizeof(char)*8)-1) << ((charsPerBlock-1)*sizeof(char)*8)) >> (j*sizeof(char)*8))) >> ((charsPerBlock-j-1)*sizeof(char)*8);
        // Testing line //
        printf("%u = (%u & %u) >> %lu\n", charsToWrite[i*charsPerBlock+j], stuffToWrite[i], (((int) pow(2, sizeof(char)*8)-1) << ((charsPerBlock-1)*sizeof(char)*8)) >> j*sizeof(char)*8, (charsPerBlock-j-1)*sizeof(char)*8);
}
```

This looks quite complicated but it's not really. I am just creating a 8 bit mask (`(int) pow(2, sizeof(char)*8)-1)`), shifting it to the first bits (`<< ((charsPerBlock-1)*sizeof(char)*8))`) then shifting it back into the right position (`>> (j*sizeof(char)*8)))`). I then `AND` this with the original block and shift it back to the lowest bits to become a character (`>> ((charsPerBlock-j-1)*sizeof(char)*8)`).

This works fine for the first block, giving me `74` or `01001010`. However, the second block gives me a very large incorrect number. I am not sure what was going wrong here as I am pretty sure my method works well so I wrote up a test line to break up the steps which yielded the following:

```
74 = (19191 & 65280) >> 8
4294967287 = (19191 & 255) >> 0
```

Which is obviously wrong.

I would appreciate any help identifying the error and how to fix it (also if there is a better way to do this).

Comment: A better way to do what? What exactly is the purpose of this function?

Comment: I explained this in at the start of the question: *I have a list of 16-bit (unsigned shorts) blocks which I receive from another part of program which I want to write to a binary file. I am trying to split these into 8-bit characters*

Comment: If it's a binary file, why not simply write the 16 bit values to the file? And what do you mean by '8-bit characters'?

Comment: `unsigned char hibyte = (val >> 8) & 0xFF, lobyte = val & 0xFF;` ... done... (Make sure `val` stays an `unsigned short`.) Please don't ask what's going wrong with your code. "Hand made" functions written by beginners are often overly complicated and turn out to be incorrect.

Comment: @EmanuelP, How would I write the 16-bit values, I am only aware that I can write single bytes (what I mean by 8-bit characters)

Comment: you are propagating signs. 4294967287 is 0xffffffff7, 47 (the 'correct' answer) is 0x000000f7

Comment: Using `pow` for this is ridiculous.  You shouldn't be using any floating point at all.  If you want to compute a power-of-two using integers, just left shift:  `1 << n` is two to the `n`.  For what you're doing, if there's any floating point at all, you made a big mistake.  At best it's a huge performance penalty, and at worst you could end up with floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: @NasserKessas Using `write(fileDes, stuffToWrite, blocks * sizeof(short))` or `fwrite(stuffToWrite, sizeof(short), blocks, filePtr)`

Comment: @TomKarzes, I thought of this, but I just haven't implemented it yet, I typecasted it to an int to remove the problem of a float though.

Comment: @NasserKessas It's a bug.  Treat it as such.

Comment: @Fe2O3, I can't believe I never thought of shifting the message block instead of the mask. Thanks for this solution

Comment: Reading and writing integers to and from file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75218040/2706707 (with sign and endianness considerations)

Comment: I think I'll just avoid all of this by writing the whole block to the file. Thanks for all the solutions.

Comment: Note aside: sizeof(char) is 1 by definition. You can (should?) omit for improved readability.

Comment: `sizeof(char)*8)-1` This does not make much sense to calculate the number of bits. `sizeof char` is defined to be 1 always. If you want to allow for characters with more than 8 bits, you might look into `CHAR_BIT`.

Answer (score 2):

> This looks quite complicated but it's not really.

It is. If you are just looking to serialize data into bytes, then all you need is this:

```c
int blocks = 1;
uint16_t stuffToWrite[blocks] = { 0b0100101011110111 };
char charsToWrite[blocks * sizeof(uint16_t)] =
{
  (stuffToWrite[0] >> 8) & 0xFFu,
  (stuffToWrite[0]     ) & 0xFFu,
};
```

This works regardless of endianess of the incoming data, but it assumes that the output data has the most significant byte first.

Similarly for a 32 bit number you'd go `>> 24`, `>> 16`, `>> 8` and `>> 0`.

Also please note that when doing bitwise arithmetic, never use the following types: signed types, `char`, floating point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I have resolved to avoid this altogether.